# Dictionaries getting deleted on their own from iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, storage, dictionary

I noticed that some of the dictionaries downloaded under `Settings app  → General → Dictionary` get deleted automatically (they do remain for some days after being downloaded, but they get deleted on their own afterward if not used in a timeline).

I heard that when the iPhone is running low on storage, it deletes unused files (like dictionaries) on its own. Is there a way to stop that?

I'm using 57.6 GB out of 64 GB on an iPhone 8 running iOS 12.2.

Comment: Are you invoking Settings app → General → Reset → Reset Keyboard Dictionary? It causes the downloaded dictionaries to be deleted.

Comment: No I do not reset anything, the dictionaries are just getting deleted on their own without any action from my part

Comment: Consider updating to the current latest version of iOS, iOS 12.3.1 and observe if that resolves the issue.

Comment: @EddGrowl Did your issue get solved? I have the same issue with dictionary on iPAD!

Comment: @FreeMind on iOS 12.3.1 everything is fine for me !

Comment: @EddGrowl So I guess I have to update! But I remember last time I updated the issue had not been solved (Update was ineffective!)

Comment: Still an issue on iOS 16.1 with not even low disk space. Pathetic.